# Return values from functions without side effects should not be ignored

Tags: c#, .net

I have this piece of code where I do the validation before a null variable, however I get this error in SonarQube, I would like to know how to solve.

```
    public int? GetCityId(string cityName, string stateName)
    {
        if (_cityData == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("You have to initialize the data first.");
       
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateName))
        {
           _cityData.Where(x => x.StateName == stateName.ToUpper() || x.StateInitials == stateName.ToUpper());
        }
        return  _cityData.Where(x =>
            x.CityName == cityName.ToUpper() || x.CityAlias == cityName.ToUpper())
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

This is the error in SonarQube:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blZ8k.jpg)

Comment: Whats the point of `_cityData.Where` if the results are not being used. Its an inefficient way of achieving absolutely nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to apply two calls to `.Where` to your query, then run it?

```cs
        var query = _cityData.Where(x =>
            x.CityName == cityName.ToUpper() || x.CityAlias == cityName.ToUpper());

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateName))
           query = query.Where(x => x.StateName == stateName.ToUpper() || x.StateInitials == stateName.ToUpper());

        return query
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```